# Why I get this Uncaught (in promise) on Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYlhO.png)

I practice React these days
but suddelny I got this error (b.AssertionError) on chrome

the funcions works well though, the error is never gone
It drives me crazy

Comment: check your code where you are expecting promise resolves. try chaining those using `.then` and `.catch` and  log the error.

Comment: I got a similar error, it's likely from an extension, not related to your code. Open your app in incognito mode and check if you get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you recently added a new chrome extension? I was getting this error after adding the Loom extension. Deleted it and the error went away.